# Separate float number awk

Tags: awk

I am looking for a way to separate the awk output into two values. 
Here is an array with values

```
  0    0.0
   1    0.1
   3    0.3
   4    0.4
   5    1.0
```

The output is printed with

```
printf("  %d    %.1f\n ",n, arr[n]
```

My question is how to get values

```
0 0 0
1 0 1
2 0 3 
4 0 4
5 1 0
```

By separating the float number inside the printf function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this `awk` with `sub`:

```
awk '{arr[$1]=$2}
END {for (n in arr) {sub(/\./, OFS, arr[n]); print n, arr[n]}}' file
```

```
0 0 0
1 0 1
2 0 3
4 0 4
5 1 0
```